# zukxd6fkxqn redirect in Firefox

Tags: 16.04, firefox, malware

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. While using Firefox occasionally the browser will open another tab then automatically close it. The tab will have an address along the lines of zukxd6fkxqn .com. I know that if I was running Windows this is probably a virus.

1. Do I have a virus? And if so how do I get rid of it?
2. I also have chromium on my computer and it is synced with my main Google account, is that compromised and if so how do I fix it?

Comment: What browser add-ons do you have installed? Does it still happen if you launch Firefox in the [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?

Comment: I am using ublock origin and privacy badger. I will attempt to replicate the problem in safe mode.

Comment: Looks like it is a redirect and not a virus but still a pain!:  http://www.myantispyware.com/2018/06/12/how-to-remove-zukxd6fkxqn-com-redirect-chrome-firefox-ie-edge/  Most of the instructions are for Windows, but some could be done in Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Problem was unable to be replicated in Safe Mode

Comment: Thanks for the advice I refreshed Firefox and it hasn't been long but I haven't seen it happen again yet. I'm going to go run a scan with clam and see what happens

Comment: Clam is still scanning but I ran a Sophos scan for good measure and it encountered a number of errors but nothing malicious was discovered

Comment: Clam just finished and it found some files in libreoffice that it didn't like but nothing that actually looks dangerous was found ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hopefully final update so this all started as I was streaming anime and there was an attempt to connect with it again, I closed the window before a tab could open but to be safe I'm switching to a different server for now